# Woocommerce regular price not getting updated

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, hook-woocommerce, code-snippets

I have added an ACF field named 'Discount_Percentage' to my woocommerce product. I want to calculate the regular price based on the discount percentage when I leave the regular price empty OR calculate the discount percentage when the discount percentage field is empty.
Following is my code snippet:

```
function wc_update_discount_and_sale_price($post_id) {
 $selling_price = get_field('_price');
 $mrp = get_field('_regular_price');
 $discount_percentage = get_field('discount_percentage');

 if(empty($selling_price) && empty($discount_percentage)){
 return;
 }

 if(!empty($selling_price) && empty($discount_percentage)){
  $discount_value = (($mrp - $selling_price)*100)/($mrp);
   update_field("discount_percentage",$discount_value,$post_id);
   return;
 }

 if(empty($selling_price) && !empty($discount_percentage)){   //not working
 $selling_price = $mrp*(100 - $discount_percentage)/100;
 update_post_meta($post_id,'_price', $selling_price);
 }
}
 add_action('save_post','wc_update_discount_and_sale_price');
```

The first two if statements are working fine. In the third if statement the regular price doesn't get populated.

**UPDATE:**
Changed ***_price*** to ***_sale_price*** worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove this `empty($selling_price) &&`in your 3rd condition because `$selling_price` is not empty as per your 2nd condition and as you said your 1st and 2nd condition working fine. so in this case your 3rd condition will not true unless `$selling_price` is empty. try the below code.

```
if( !empty( $discount_percentage ) ){   //not working
    $selling_price = $mrp * ( 100 - $discount_percentage ) / 100;
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_price', $selling_price );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!
Instead of using **_price** I changed it to **_sale_price** and it worked as intended.

I'm trying to render the values in realtime(as I type in the sale price field the discount field should update automatically). Currently it updates when the posts get updated or saved. I don't know how to achieve that.